# Thinking in binary

Tags: number-systems

I have been thinking about how to think in binary notation. I know that decimal notation is just one way to represent numbers. Yet the decimal notation is so ingrained into my concept of numbers, that it is hard to see, that it is only representation. If I look at a binary number, I need to convert it to decimal to understand it. I know it is an unnecessary step.

I would like like to be able to think in both binary and decimal systems (and I also plan to be able to think in other numeral systems).

I do not have an exact reason for why I want to be able to do this. I feel that it would allow me to appreciate and understand math more closely and maybe to get a feel for the underlying structure of the number systems, which I do not possess at the moment. I also have a feeling that it might be useful for kids to be able to think in multiple numeral systems. I want to try it with my own kids. I suspect it will deepen the intuitive understanding of orders of magnitude and it may even help with spoken language learning. I could elaborate more, but I suspect, this is not the place.

I feel numeral languages are similar to spoken languages - some ideas are more easily expresses in English, but others are more easily expressed in Japanese.

The question - is there a "language" on how to think in binary? 
Let me explain. I do not want to use ones and zeros, because it is hard for me, not to see a decimal number in it. And I want to be able to read it and have a grammar for orders of magnitude. You would usually read binary number 1001 (9 in base 10) as one-zero-zero-one, but it is hard to understand. I would like something similar to the decimal system. You say twenty-two thousand, four hundred sixty-seven, not two-two-four-six-seven.
I have come up with my own binary language, but I wonder if there is already some standard way. So I'm not reinventing the wheel. I don't know where to look or how to write a query for it.
And a second question. If there is no standard binary language, is there someplace on the internet where I could discuss and share my language?

In case you wonder how this language looks like, there are a few examples:

\begin{array} {|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
Classical\ binary\ notation &Decimal\ notation&New\ binary\ notation &Pronunciation \\
\hline
0 &0& Ɔ&ba \\
\hline
1 &1& ſ&ta \\
\hline
10 &2& ſƆ&tajba \\
\hline
11 &3& ſſ&tajta \\
\hline
100 &4& ſƆƆ&tambajba \\
\hline
1011 &11& ſƆſſ&rata\ bamtajta \\
\hline
10000 &16& ſƆƆƆƆ&ratajba \\
\hline
10001 &17& ſƆƆƆſ&ratajba\ bambajta \\
\hline
101010 &42& ſƆſƆſƆ& ratambajta\ bamtajba\\
\hline
\end{array}

Comment: I've never seen anything like it, but it's interesting. I'm pretty bad with languages so I'd be especially bad at this. That being said, I don't really see any purpose to being able to "speak" binary.

Comment: Well. I can see why it could be useful, but it's not easy to explain. Since I speak two languages fluently (Czech and English), I know that it is easier to think about some ideas in English rather than Czech and vice versa. By knowing more languages, I can get a more in-depth understanding - I can take multiple points of view. I suspect it can also be applied with numeral systems. You can think about the same thing differently and gain new knowledge. I also suspect that it will be simpler to explain some aspects of arithmetics to kids using binary language rather than decimal language.

Comment: This might be of interest to you. The article list various languages with non-base-10 number words https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/31879/12-mind-blowing-number-systems-other-languages

Comment: Also see here http://www.sf.airnet.ne.jp/ts/language/number.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference to other non-decimal number languages. I'm aware of their existence and want to learn some of them too. But in this question, I was asking specifically about binary numbers.